# How to make ValidateSet show different data depending on previous parameters

Tags: powershell

I want to validate user inputs in a script which sets the attributes Company, Department, and Office in Active Directory.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$ApprovedLocations = #A table with known Company,Department,Office values
Class Company : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [String[]] GetValidValues(){
        return $global:ApprovedLocations.Company
    }
}
Class Department : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [String[]] GetValidValues(){
        return $global:ApprovedLocations.Department
    }
}
Class Office : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [String[]] GetValidValues(){
        return $global:ApprovedLocations.Office
    }
}    
function Set-AttributeTest{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Name,
        [ValidateSet([Company])][string]$Company,
        [ValidateSet([Department])][string]$Department,
        [ValidateSet([Office])][string]$Office
    )
#Do stuff
}
```

This works to prevent typos. But since not all companies have the same departments and offices I'd like the ValidateSet to allow different values depending on previous parameter. E.g. only allow office and department combinations which actually exist at the different companies.

Example:

```
Company A
      |-- HR
      |    |-- Office A
      |    |-- Office B
      |
      |-- IT
           |-- Office C
           |-- Office D

Company B
      |-- Design
      |    |-- Office E
      |    |-- Office F
      |
      |-- Finance
// ...etc
```

Is there a way to do this with parameters in Powershell or should I rethink the entire thing?

Comment: Where do you plan on getting the company-specific hierarchies from? The feature you're looking for is [dynamicparam](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#dynamic-parameters) btw

Comment: Yeah, dynamicparams is exactly what I was looking for, probably in combination with ValidateSets as @filimonic mentioned. As for the hierarchy, we plan on using a database with approved values filled in by our Identity Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are variants:

- [Dynamic Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#dynamic-parameters)
- [Argument Completer](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#argumentcompleter-script-block)
- [Dynamic ValidateSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7#dynamic-validateset-values) (**PSv7+**)

---

Example using **Dynamic Parameters** for single dynamic parameter.

```
$global:CompanyDepts = @{ 
    'Contoso' = @('Sales', 'IT')
    'Adatum' = @('HR', 'Shipping')
}

function Test-DynParam {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [ValidateSet('Contoso', 'Adatum')]
      [String]$Company
  )

  DynamicParam {
    if (-not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Company) -and $global:CompanyDepts.ContainsKey($Company) )
    {
      $attrDept = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]::new()
      $attrDept.ParameterSetName = 'CompanySet'
      $attrDept.Mandatory = $true
            
      $attrDeptValidation = [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute]::new([String[]]$global:CompanyDepts[$Company])

      $attributeCollection = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
      $attributeCollection.Add($attrDept)
      $attributeCollection.Add($attrDeptValidation )

      $param = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new('Department', [String], $attributeCollection)
      $paramDict = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
      $paramDict.Add('Department', $param)
      return $paramDict
    }
  }

  process {
    $PSBoundParameters.Keys | % { Write-Host "$($_)=$($PSBoundParameters[$_])" }
  }
}
```

---

Note that you SHOULD help users to achieve best usage expirience, so remember that one user can start typing `My-Cmdlet -Company ...` presuming `Department` autocomplete, and another user prefer typing `My-Cmdlet -Department ...` presuming `Company` autocomplete, so there sjhould be a combination of  ParameterSets and DynamicParams

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is exactly what I was looking for. :) Yeah, a combination of both will probably be least confusing for the users.